# Does it exist anything like DWR for PHP?

Tags: php, dwr

I'm a Java web programmer used to work with DWR and now I have to develop with PHP. I've just created my model with PHP 5 classes and I'd like to access my PHP Classes throught AJAX directly from JavaScript as DWR does.

It's a very simple web and I'm not using heavy frameworks such as CakePHP or Zend, only a bunch of classes modelling data and another bunch with the "bussiness logic". Then every single PHP page should invoke the proper method in logic classes, obtain an instance of a model class and present it to the user.

(thanks anybody trying to help)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://www.xajax-project.org/
but i think Jquery + PhpBackend do it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use CodeIgniter, which probably falls in to the "heavy framework" category, but is at least much lighter than CakePHP (and lighter than Zend too, I think).

http://codeigniter.com/